# Populate jquery modal dialog with MVC partial view async, and show in center of screen

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to use the jquery modal dialog to show a partial view async when clicking on something. Pretty simple, and there are loads of questions on this, but I can't seem to get it work. I have had the modal displaying, but not in the center. And I've read it's because I'm populating the div *after* the dialog is displayed, therefore the position is relative to the empty div, not the populated one - and I've proved this to be the case by showing some static content, and it centers fine.

So now, I'm trying to get the partial view first, then show the dialog in the load() callback, but it's not working. I get an error on the 'dialog('open')' line, because the dialog method is undefined. Here's my code:

(P.S. I'm new to javascript/jQuery, so sorry if it's pretty obvious)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#my-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#show-modal').click(function() {
            $('#my-dialog').load("@Url.Action("MyActionOnController")", function() {
                $('#my-dialog').dialog('open');
            });

            return false;
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="my-dialog"></div>

<a href="#" id="show-modal">Click Me </a>
```

Help appreciated!

**Edit** I've changed the code to match Darin's and uploaded an image showing what the problem appears to be?

[image: wtf]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the problem:

The partial view I was returning for my modal dialog was created using the MVC scaffolding for an edit view, which by default includes some jQuery scripts which were already included in the layout page, which must have been causing the problem.

All working nicely now!

Answer (score 13):

Your code looks fine and it worked when I tested it. Here's my full test case:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult MyActionOnController()
    {
        // TODO: You could return a PartialView here of course
        return Content("<div>Hello world</div>", "text/html");
    }
}
```

View (~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml):

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#my-dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true
            });

            $('#show-modal').click(function() {
                $('#my-dialog').load("@Url.Action("MyActionOnController")", function() {
                    $(this).dialog('open');
                });
                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-dialog"></div>
    <a href="#" id="show-modal">Click Me </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dammit! Why won't mine work lol. Incidentally - if you were trying to do this, would this be the preferable way of writing it?

Comment: @DavidMasters84, yes that's how I would do it. Make sure that you have properly included the jquery-ui script. Also make sure that you don't get an error message on the server. Use FireBug to to see the exact AJAX request. If there were errors you would see them.

Comment: there is a subtle difference with your code, in that the dialog definition and click handler are both in the same block. I've copied your code but still no joy. I've got the same script includes as you too :\

Comment: @DavidMasters84, but does this script exist in the script folder of your web application. Also are you getting some errors in FireBug? Also does your controller return a hardcoded content as in my example or are you returning some actual partial view?

Comment: It returns a partial view. I know that the request is working fine, as whilst debugging I can hover over $(#my-dialog') in the call back and see it has the correct HTML from the partial view.

Comment: I've just created a new project with the same code and it runs fine. I guess there must be some sort of conflict some where

Answer (score 0):

Possible scope issue?

You're effectively declaring two `document.ready` functions. Just put all of the code inside:

```
$(function () {

    });
```

Comment: Actually it's not a problem that you have 2 document.ready functions. jQuery is intelligent enough to merge them into a single one. As long as they are not nested it is OK.