# Load jqueryui modal dialog from function in external js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

In ASP.NET MVC, I am trying to show a jqueryUI modal dialog, by calling a function that resides in an external js file. The reason for this is that i want to have a js method written somewhere and just call it with some parameters, instead of copypasting it on every page.

this is my CustomFunctions.js file:

```
function CustomFunctions() { };

CustomFunctions.prototype.loadModalDialog = function (dialogDivID, callerElementDivID, dialogSize, actionControllerName, container)
{
  var dialogElement = $('#' + dialogDivID);
  var callerElement = $('#' + callerElementDivID);
  dialogElement.dialog
  (
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "slide",
        width: dialogSize,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true
    }
  );

callerElement.click(function() 
{
    dialogElement.load("@Url.Action(" + actionControllerName +")", function() 
    {
        $(container).dialog('open');
    });
    return false;
})
```

}

now, on my List.cshtml view, I have written the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
        "click me", 
        "List", 
        new {string.Empty},
        new { onclick = "Javascript:showModal();" }
        );

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom");
<script>
    function showModal()
    {
        var custom = new CustomFunctions();
        custom.loadModalDialog("my-dialog", "show-modal", 400, "List", this);
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that the modal dialog does not pop. On client side debugging, it enters the loadModalDialog, it finds all variables properly, it goes through all the js code, throws no error (which puzzles me) but does not show the dialog.

Am I missing something? 
Thanks,

Comment: Does the element with id `my-dialog` exist in the DOM?

Comment: when debugging it finds it correctly as a HTMLDivElement. Does that answer your question? Thanks,

Comment: Have you inspected the `<div>` to see if the appropriate classes have been applied to it for `ui-dialog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will not work in an external js file

> "@Url.Action(" + actionControllerName +")"

this works when inline with the the template because the tempplate is prased and rendered before it's sent to the client. when this is put into an exteneral js file it's a literal string.

> custom.loadModalDialog("my-dialog", "show-modal", 400, "List",
>   this /*probably not what you'd expect*/);

passing `this` at this point in the code is passing either the document or window object. you then try to call `dialog('open')` on the container, which is not the dialog object you are expecting.

There is also the issue of calling jquery outside of the `document.ready` event. unless `showModal()` is called after the page loads the jquery functions will not work.

Any of the latest bowsers have a javascript/console for debugging js.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I got it to work on a page, then I moved the method in a separate js and made it configurable. Why should actioncontrollerName not work ? This is taken from Darin's answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846139/populate-jquery-modal-dialog-with-mvc-partial-view-async-and-show-in-center-of

Comment: and your example with "this" doesnt work, and i dont see why it should - my intention is to call the javascript, not to send the Model object as a querystring (which is what your code does, I just tried it)

Comment: i edited my response above. but yes, the code above doesn't work. I'm only quoting your OP to point out where the problems are.

Comment: I did more research on the Url.Action and it seems you are absolutely correct. What I am doing cannot happen. So I will accept this as an answer, but I will need to keep looking for alternatives to centralize my javascripts in a single file, as opposed to have them copypasted on all views in my MVC Project (this is the purpose of my question). Thank you

Comment: pass the url instead of `controllerActionName` to the function. then call `@Url.Action(...)` from the videw when configuring the custom object.